# How to set multiple certificates for AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, listener, aws-cloudformation

Hi I have problem setting multiple certificates for ALB listener.
Here is fragment of my CF template:

```
  DiscoveryListenerHTTPS:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn:
      - DiscoveryLoadBalancer
      - DiscoveryLoadBalancerTargetGroup
    Properties:
      Certificates:
       - CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateArn1
       - CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateArn2
```

and response is:
`Up to '1' certificate ARNs can be specified, but '2' were specified (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TooManyCertificates; Request ID: XXXXXXXXX)`

Comment: The documentation states: If you specify HTTPS or TLS for the Protocol property, you must specify exactly one certificate. You haven't included a Protocol in your template but it's a mandatory field, so I'm not sure why it's not present.

Comment: @jarmod, 
1) You can add many certificates but not the Listener resource directly, instead you should use the ListenerCertificate resource. cf. answers bellow.
2) I think the missing Protocol and port were removed for the sack of simplicity.

Answer (score 22):

EDIT : improved answer thanks to @chris-pollard and @adamkgray answers

This works for me, you can specify multiple SSL certificates for an HTTPS listener.

For HTTPS, you are not allowed to specify directly multiple certificates on the [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener.html) resource.
Instead you have to create a [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenercertificate.html) resource in your template for additional certificates.

Here is an example of a listener by 443 port using a default certificate and then a certificate list with at least one certificate and associated to the listener that was previously created:

```yaml
Listener443:
    DependsOn:
    - LoadBalancer
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateARN
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:        
            ContentType: text/plain
            MessageBody: "Not Found"
            StatusCode: 404
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS

  CertificatesList:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate
    Properties: 
      Certificates: 
        - CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateARN2
      ListenerArn: !Ref Listener443
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a little clunky; the CF template for creating the listener only sets the default cert.

You should be able to add additional certs to the listener with this object: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenercertificate.html

Comment: It is actually a great design. You can create a load balancer listener in one stack and export it. Other application stacks can add certifcates for their application without modifying the load balancer stacks

Answer (score 5):

Came here looking for the same answer. Found that the answer was not clearly laid out in the comments/answers, so I'm gonna do that. Although you can specify multiple SSL certificates for an HTTPS listener, you are not allowed to specify multiple certificates on the HTTPS listener resource directly in the CFN template. You have to create another resource in your template for additional certificates like this:

```
AdditionalListenerCertificates:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate
        Properties:
            Certificates:
              - CertificateArn: !Join
                - ":"
                - - "arn:aws:acm"
                  - !Ref AWS::Region
                  - !Ref AWS::AccountId
                  - !Join ["/", ["certificate", "<you-certificate-id>"]]
            ListenerArn: !Ref HTTPSListener
```

Comment: One note - if you create the certificate in the same template, just use ```!Ref <Certificate>```, otherwise pass the full arn as a parameter. Please, for the love of god, do not build strings with ```!Join``` as it reads bad and breaks even worse.

Comment: Thanks so much for this comment! Ive seen a lot of sample templates on github which build strings using join, and i thought it was common practice. Nice to hear opposing views. Is there a best practices guide that you can reccomend to avoid this sort of thing, or does this particular example just come from experience?

Comment: For example, ```!Sub "arn:aws:acm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}/certificate/${certificate_id}>" ```, where `certificate_id` passed as a parameter. More compact and (IMHO) readable vs double `!Join`. I'd also suggest to avoid constructing certificate (and any really) `arn` on the fly when you actually can pass the whole `arn` as a parameter - just too much effort. There is no best practice, per se, AFAIK, take it more as opinion.